# sql lite update query list parameter issue

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a simple sql lite query using room like this.

```
@Query("UPDATE MYTABLE SET CAT_ID = :idCata WHERE MYTABLE_ID IN (:listIds)")
int updateAll(long idCata, String listIds);
```

Where CAT_ID is defined as a nullable foreign key and MYTABLE_ID is primary key for MYTABLE.

All is working if i use one value in listIds parameter. 
If i put something like "1,5" this does not update the rows in the database. If i use "1" or "5" as single value in listIds, all is ok.

I have nothing in logcat or something like issue in logs.

Can someone explain me why ?

**EDIT : I posted answer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, note i used long array because the query is updating foreign key values which cannot be typed as string.
I think it is more elegant and safer. So the final code is :

```
String[] ids = listIds.split(",");
long[] idsForQuery = new long[ids.length];
try{
    for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
        idsForQuery[i] = Long.parseLong(ids[i]);
    }
    mDao.updateAll(idCata, idsForQuery);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // something wrong with ids type !!
}
```

And in the dao, the sql lite query.

```
@Query("UPDATE MYTABLE SET CAT_ID = :idCata WHERE MYTABLE_ID IN (:listIds)")
int updateAll(long idCata, long[] listIds);
```

Thanks to MikeT for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that 1,5 will be enclosed in single quotes and will be treated as a string. So only rows that have 1,5 as the value would be updated.

When you use IN the values should in an array Room will then build the correct IN clause. So you want :-

```
 @Query("UPDATE MYTABLE SET CAT_ID = :idCata WHERE MYTABLE_ID IN (:listIds)")
 int updateAll(long idCata, String[] /*<<<<<<<<<<*/ listIds);
```

- Obviously you need to split listIds into the array.

or

```
  int updateAll(long idCata,listIds.split(','));
```

- which does the split

Comment: Your right, may i use something like @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN(:userIds)")
 public abstract List findByIds(int[] userIds); ?

Comment: @Zhar I believe that you just need to convert (split) the string into a String[] of the values.